# Input not an X.509 certificate

Tags: java, certificate, jks

I am trying to import a certificate for a Java app to run (I am a beginner) and I am using this command in cmd:

```
keytool -importcert -file mycertfile.jks-keystore cacerts -alias "Alias"
```

and it gives me this error:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate
```

I also tried this command :

```
keytool -importcert -file mycertfile.pem -keystore keystore.jks -alias "Alias" -storepass <PASSWORD>
```

But it doesn't work

I would like the certificate to be added and when I run the app to not give me errors

Comment: I used to this manuals https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/ggezu/index.html. and https://arunpc.com/2012/05/11/keytool-for-dummies/ Certificate was added successfully.